# How to write the loss when it is the minimum of some function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I know that some of the targets is to minimize the loss function, but **what if the loss is also a function including minimum**, how could I write the loss correctly? This may seems a little confusing, let me take an example.

The loss function is defined as follows:
[image]

where `f1, f2` is the feature map output of some network and `b` is a shift distance. The shift of a feature map is like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` shift one step left is `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`.

The question is how could I write this loss function using tensorflow since b is not trainable and the trainable variable is the weight in network to generate the feature map. It seems possible in Torch since I could somehow make a **for loop** maybe. How could I achieve this in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensor flow has a `tf.minimum(x,y)` which returns the minimum between x and y.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/minimum

You can trust that if there is a tensorflow operation for it than it automatically calculates the gradient, and therefore can be optimized.

Comment: But how could I specify the value b in the formula above, since I think `b` cannot be defined as a placeholder?